# SQL Left join with having clause

Tags: sql, oracle, having

So I am having this sql code:

```
select stone_number,stone_size,stone_shape,stone_weight 
from stone
left Join stone_price stp on stp.id_stone = stone.id_stone
group by stone_number,stone_size,stone_shape,stone_weight 
having  avg(stp.price) < stp.price;
```

Sqldeveloper returns: not a group by expression tho I still have group by in my code.
My goal is to get stone items which price is higher then average price of all stones.

Comment: [Is it true that using INNER JOIN after any OUTER JOIN will essentially invalidate the effects of OUTER JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55111083/3404097)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a window function:

```
select *
from (
  select stone_number,stone_size,stone_shape,stone_weight, 
         stp.price, 
         avg(stp.price) over () as avg_price
  from stone
    left Join stone_price stp on stp.id_stone = stone.id_stone
)  
where price > avg_price;
```

Note that the condition on the outer joined table essentially turns your outer join into an inner join. If you also want to include rows that did not have a match in `stone_price` you need

```
where price is null
   or price > avg_price;
```

Otherwise you can just change the `left join` to a "plain" `join`

---

Another option is a simple sub-select:

```
select stone_number,stone_size,stone_shape,stone_weight, 
from stone
  left Join stone_price stp on stp.id_stone = stone.id_stone
where stp.price > (select avg(price) from stone_price);
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use a stored procedure, You could set a variable like this:

```
DECLARE @average_price INT
SET @average_price = (SELECT Avg(stone_price) from stone
```

Then in your SELECT statement

```
select stone_number,stone_size,stone_shape,stone_weight 
from stone
left Join stone_price stp on stp.id_stone = stone.id_stone
WHERE stone_price > @average_price
```

Comment: That is not valid for Oracle

Comment: That seems like a good idea, I never saw or done that only some basic SQL but I get the idea. I'm working in SqlDeveloper and I get error at @ when declaring the variable: Encountered the symbol "@" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
   exists prior

Comment: Oh right... this is SQL for SQL Server. But that would be one approach to take in Oracle. Declare a variable, get the average and then use that in the where clause.